# How do I fix GLib Error when updating packages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glib

Hello I'm getting the following error trying sudo apt-get update. What may be the problem? I use Ubuntu 20.04

```
GLib:ERROR:../../../glib/gutf8.c:1782:g_utf8_strreverse: assertion failed: (r >= result)
Aborted
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Follow the link, please http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7/ubuntu → is for Ubuntu's 12.04 , 14.04 , 14.10 . .... Please delete non valid repos in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*